# How to include task parameter In array of tasks exception handling

Tags: .net, exception, parallel-processing, async-await

The thread [Nesting await in Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach/25877042#25877042) has an answer suggested to use  Task.WhenAll to run multiple (MaxDegreeOfParallelism)  asynchronous tasks in parallel, not waiting until previous task is completed.

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(
      this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body) 
{ 
    return Task.WhenAll( 
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) 
        select Task.Run(async delegate { 
            using (partition) 
                while (partition.MoveNext()) 
                    await body(partition.Current).ContinueWith(t => 
                          {
                              //observe exceptions
                          });
})); 
}
```

And call it like

```
ids.ForEachAsync(10,  async id =>
{
    ICustomerRepo repo = new CustomerRepo();  
    var cust = await repo.GetCustomer(id);  
    customers.Add(cust);  
});
```

If body has a parameter, I want to know parameter value when handling exceptions.e.g. If task body failed for  id , I need to log exception, specifying, that it happened for particular id.

I’ve looked at
[Accessing values in Task.ContinueWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716093/accessing-values-in-task-continuewith), but wasn’t able to access parameters when t.IsFaulted.

Finally I’ve added try/catch inside lambda body and it seems to work

```
ids.ForEachAsync(10,  async id =>
{
    try
    {
        ICustomerRepo repo = new CustomerRepo();
        var cust = await repo.GetCustomer(id);
        customers.Add(cust);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e,” id=“+ id);
    }
});
```

However I am not sure, does it work correctly(i.e asynchronously, without blocking).

Later the author of the original answer [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach/11565531#comment82950771_25877042) to use var current = partition.Current before await body and then use current in the continuation (ContinueWith(t => { ... }). –

Can anyone confirm, which approach is better? Any disadvantages of each of approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping `await` in `try`/`catch` is fine, see: [Catch an exception thrown by an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383310/catch-an-exception-thrown-by-an-async-method). No big difference from my suggestion (capturing `partition.Current` and injecting into the `ContinueWith` continuation), except maybe it's a bit more efficient since no capturing is involved. Also it's a bit more readable and elegant I think, `ContinueWith` is kind of the "old" way of doing things (pre `async`/`await`).

Note that your example passes the burden of exception handling to the caller (who in this case calls `_logger.LogError`). You need to make sure that's what you want, as opposed to a catch-all embedded in the `ForEachAsync` code itself to handle the case where he caller does let an exception slip through. Something like:

```
while (partition.MoveNext()) 
{
    try
    {
        await body(partition.Current)
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // of course here you don't know the type of T (partition.Current)
        // or anything else about the operation for that matter
        LogError("error processing: " + partition.Current + ": " + e); 
    }
}
```